# How to contact Salesforce support

Tags: query

I have queried Salesforce data in the organization and I get timeout issues, how can I contact Salesforce's support team after loging in?
can anyone please suggest where I can reach them?

Comment: you question has nothing to do with the title. fixed it for you

Answer (score 1):

go to https://success.salesforce.com/successHome

The page footer contains the Contact Support option

[image]